# Understanding 'ccdc' algorithm in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, change-detection

I want to know how the 'ccdc' algorithm, which is deployed on GEE, detects changes.

Does the algorithm use the method on the left, the method on the right, or some other method?

[image]

---the picture came from [《Continuous monitoring of land disturbance based on Landsat time series》](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0034425719301002?via%3Dihub)

The function of ccdc in Google Earth Engine is:

```
ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Ccdc()
```

Comment: Please always include formatted text rather than pictures of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhere in between, since it's derived from the V12.30 MATLAB implementation, and you can manually specify the number of observations required to detect a change (it defaults to 6).  There is no angle adjustment.